# How can I deselect text using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable (jQuery UI) element with "canceled" text on it. Here's what I mean:

```
$('#main').draggable({
        cancel: '#main>* *',
        start: function(){
          // deselect text
        }
});
```

When I drag the element, I often select the text by accident. I want to deselect the text when the element is dragged.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Clear document selection  `document.selection.empty();`

Something like:

```
 $('#main').draggable({
     cancel: '#main>* *',
     start: function(){
      // deselect text
      document.selection.empty();
     }
 });
```

Comment: `document.selection` is undefined in both `FF` and `Chrome`. Use `document.getSelection()` instead.

Answer (score 104):

To deselect everything you can use:

```
document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

Comment: This works way better because I found that the checked answer throws an exception if no selected text is found.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI now includes `.disableSelection()`, which you can use to prevent the text inside your elements from being selected. The API documentation on it isn't hugely useful, but: http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/

As an aside, Eric G's answer proved supremely helpful for me when creating my own "text highlighting" tool - as Lawrence remarked, it won't throw out an error if no text has been selected.

Comment: disableSelection is deprecated (and if you make just a few tests you will quickly find it not working)